# Getting CORS errors on mainnet.smartpy.io with Taquito

Tags: smartpy, taquito, mainnet

```
const Tezos = new TezosToolkit('https://mainnet.smartpy.io');
    
const network = {
    type: 'mainnet',
    rpcUrl: 'https://mainnet.smartpy.io'
};
```

This is what I've been using to hook up Taquito, has been working fine for weeks, but yesterday I started getting CORS errors on the normalized endpoint

`https://mainnet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT1HbQepzV1nVGg8QVznG7z4RcHseD5kwqBn/script/normalized`

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mainnet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT1HbQepzV1nVGg8QVznG7z4RcHseD5kwqBn/script/normalized' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on there?

I've changed the mainnet to `https://mainnet.api.tez.ie` which seems to have fixed the issue for now. Would like to know if there's anything I've done wrong that might have caused the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem on SmartPy side.

Is this working now?

Comment: Yeah, can confirm is now working again, cheers!